# persist celery events while receiver is down

Tags: events, celery, monitoring

What happens to celery's events when my receiver is down?
According to documentation(https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#real-time-processing) I need to run a separate process that is listening for celery events and process them.
But, if i have to shutdown the receiver process for maintance or other purpose, all events are lost for ever?

Can i persist this events?

Answer (score 0):

Long answer:  it depends on your broker choice.
Short answer:  the three most popular brokers with celery are RabbitMQ, redis, and SQS.  Each one offers some degree of persistence and.  Rabbit MQ and SQS are message queueing services that offer "guaranteed delivery" of messages once and only once.  The default redis configuration will persist messages in RAM and save them to disk after a maximum of fifteen minutes, so if redis shuts down within that fifteen minute time span, you will lose messages / tasks.

Comment: When i speak about events I mean monitoring events(like task start, task end, task fail ecc). According to documentation this events are sent throught a pub/sub channel with no persistency.
PS: I'm using redis as broker